# Calling a React component with a useContext hook

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-context

I have a `Parent` component that renders a `Spawner` component. The `Spawner` is responsible for displaying which `child` component to display based on certain conditions.

I wrapped the `Parent` in a context, because the `child` created needs to access some props inside the `Parent`.

Below is a sample code:

```
// Parent file
export const ParentContext = createContext({
  prop1: '',
  prop2: '',
})

const Parent = () => {
  // An example condition
  const condition = 'child1'

  return (
    <ParentContext.Provider value={{ prop1: 'prop1', prop2: 'prop2'}}>
      {/* some other jsx */}
      <Spawner type={condition} />
    </ParentContext.Provider>
  )
}

// Spawner file
const component = [
  { type: 'child1', Component: Child1 },
  { type: 'child2', Component: Child2 },
  { type: 'child3', Component: Child3 },
]

export const Spawner = ({ type }) => {
  const ChildToDisplay = component.find((comp) => comp.type === type)?.Component || () => null;

  return (
    <>
      <ChildToDisplay />
    </>
  )
}
```

The child components uses the `useContext` hook

```
// in each child component, a useContext hook is called
const Child1 = () => {
  const context = useContext(ParentContext)

  return (
    // some jsx
  )
}
```

I'm getting an error: `Cannot access 'Child1' before initialization.`

If I remove the `useContext`, the error gets resolved. But I need the context to render something conditionally in the child.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance it could be because the posted are all in one file and `Child1` might be used before it was defined?

I tried the code but in separated files, and it seems to be working, here is a quick demo for the experiment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ypszju?file=src/App.js)

*ParentContext.js*

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

export const ParentContext = createContext({
  prop1: '',
  prop2: '',
});
```

*Child1.js*

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ParentContext } from './ParentContext';

// in each child component, a useContext hook is called
const Child1 = () => {
  const { prop1, prop2 } = useContext(ParentContext);
  return <h1>{`${prop1} ${prop2}`}</h1>;
};

export default Child1;
```

*App.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Child1 from './Child1';
import { ParentContext } from './ParentContext';

const Parent = () => {
  // An example condition
  const condition = 'child1';

  return (
    <ParentContext.Provider value={{ prop1: 'Hello', prop2: 'World' }}>
      {/* some other jsx */}
      <Spawner type={condition} />
    </ParentContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Spawner file
const component = [
  { type: 'child1', Component: Child1 },
  { type: 'child1', Component: Child1 },
  { type: 'child1', Component: Child1 },
];

export const Spawner = ({ type }) => {
  const ChildToDisplay =
    component.find((comp) => comp.type === type)?.Component || (() => null);

  return <>{ChildToDisplay && <ChildToDisplay />}</>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified this, but the `Parent`, `Spawner` and `Child` components are  in separate files. I've solved my problem by placing the `component` array inside the actual `Spawner` component. The error is gone now, even when `useContext` is used. Please do tell me if you know why this is the case, because before I implemented the `useContext`, there was no error.